# What is the use of a Connection pool and is it harmful?

Tags: java, hibernate, database-connection

For Hibernate we can use a Connection pool to manage connections inside of it. Is the state of the connections inside the pool opened? Or is it closed? And if the connections are open is there a possible security threat and a threat to the Database.

And we are using Oracle as the database- so is there a internal mechanism inside Oracle to disconnect unused connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of pooling the database connections is to have a set of **open** connections so that every time the application tries to open a new connection, the pool transparently returns already opened connection. This is much faster than opening new connection every time.

From the database perspective it looks like your application has open but idle database connection (like if you would open SQL console and not run any queries).

I am not a security expert, also I don't know how secure is Oracle connection and TCP/IP stack. But the fact that the idle connection remains for several seconds between your application shouldn't be a problem. Millions of applications are using database connection pooling (in fact, I can't think of any application *not* using it) and I have never heard of any attack vector targeting it. Remember that pooled connections are still subject of datbase authorization and authentication.

Consider tunneling or encrypting the database connection if it worries you that much (or if the database connection is over the Internet, not intranet.

Comment: What about Database corruptions? Does the database file get corrupted

Comment: @Duli-chan: it has nothing to do with connection pooling. Also RDBMS are built on top of ACID principle, no corruption should **ever* occur.

Answer (score 4):

The connections inside the pool are open (at least for some time period; depending on your pool implementation idle connections might get closed). Creating and opening new database connections can be expensive. Pooling is used to reduce this cost.

There's really no more security threat with using connection pooling than there would be without. In either case, your application still has the same level of access to the database; the same level of damage can be done regardless of if a connection has to be opened first or not.

Comment: Also, depending on the implementation a pool will have features to cleanup stale or dead connections. Connection pooling is meant to be a performance enhancement.

Answer (score -2):

All this issues are transparent to the using code. You will make this questions only if you implement a connection pool by yourself. If you use a well known (such as c3p0) you do not get in touch with that issues because you are coding against the DataSource interface.

(That does'nt mean that this libraries are free per-se of bugs, memory leaks or orphane open connections).